# what is the right way to compare two fields inside directive realization in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So, what the problem. I have two input fields newPassword and oldPassword. I want to check if these two fields are equals show the error message. 
**Form** looks like:

```
<form name="passwordForm" ng-submit="submitPasswordForm()" modelAttribute="userPasswordChange" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
            <input path="oldPassword" type="password" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" placeholder="Old Password" ng-model="user.oldPassword" minlength="5" maxlength="128" required/>
            <br>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.oldPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.required">Old Password field can not be empty. Please check it and try again.</span>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.minlength || passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.maxlength">Old password field size must be between 5 and 128</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input path="newPassword" type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" ng-model="user.newPassword" minlength="5" maxlength="128" required diff-values="oldPassword"/>
            <br>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.newPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.newPassword.$error.required">New Password field can not be empty. Please check it and try again.</span>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.newPassword.$error.minlength || passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.maxlength">New Password field size must be between 5 and 128</span>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.newPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.newPassword.$error.differentValues">New Password and Old Password fields must have different values.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input path="confirmPassword" type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm password" ng-model="user.confirmPassword" minlength="5" maxlength="128" same required/>
            <br>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.confirmPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.confirmPassword.$error.required">Confirm password field can not be empty. Please check it and try again.</span>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.confirmPassword.$error.minlength || passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.maxlength">Confirm password field size must be between 5 and 128</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input id="save" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" onsubmit="submitPasswordForm()"  
               ng-disabled="passwordForm.oldPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.oldPassword.$invalid
                           || passwordForm.newPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.newPassword.$invalid
                           || passwordForm.confirmPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.confirmPassword.$invalid"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

So if I have understood right, I have to create **my own directive**. So I realized it in this way:

```
var postPasswordForm = angular.module('postPasswordForm', []);
    postPasswordForm.directive('diffValues', function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                var compareWith = document.getElementById(attr.diffValues).value;
                var currentVar = value;
                ctrl.$setValidity('differentValues', compareWith !== currentVar);

                console.log(scope);    
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is that for this task I also need to observe when old password change, and according to expression show\hide this span:

```
<span ng-show="passwordForm.newPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.newPassword.$error.differentValues">New Password and Old Password fields must have different values.</span>
```

and of course change this value

```
passwordForm.newPassword.$error.differentValues:
```

Can someone help me and explain how to do that in the right way? I will appreciate any idea, explanations, and links.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that in a next way:

```
<form name="passwordForm" ng-submit="submitPasswordForm()" modelAttribute="userPasswordChange" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
            <input path="oldPassword" type="password" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" placeholder="Old Password" ng-model="user.oldPassword" minlength="5" maxlength="128" required/>
            <br>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.oldPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.required">Old Password field can not be empty. Please check it and try again.</span>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.minlength || passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.maxlength">Old password field size must be between 5 and 128</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input path="newPassword" type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" ng-model="user.newPassword" minlength="5" maxlength="128" required diff-values="user.oldPassword"/>
            <br>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.newPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.newPassword.$error.required">New Password field can not be empty. Please check it and try again.</span>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.newPassword.$error.minlength || passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.maxlength">New Password field size must be between 5 and 128</span>
            **CHANGED HERE:**<span ng-show="passwordForm.newPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.newPassword.$error.differentValues">New Password field must be different from the Old Password field.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input path="confirmPassword" type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm password" ng-model="user.confirmPassword" minlength="5" maxlength="128" same required/>
            <br>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.confirmPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.confirmPassword.$error.required">Confirm password field can not be empty. Please check it and try again.</span>
            <span ng-show="passwordForm.confirmPassword.$error.minlength || passwordForm.oldPassword.$error.maxlength">Confirm password field size must be between 5 and 128</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input id="save" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" onsubmit="submitPasswordForm()"  
               ng-disabled="passwordForm.oldPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.oldPassword.$invalid
                           || passwordForm.newPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.newPassword.$invalid
                           || passwordForm.confirmPassword.$dirty && passwordForm.confirmPassword.$invalid"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

And directive function changed to this one:

```
postPasswordForm.directive('diffValues', function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
            otherModelValue: "=diffValues"
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.diffValues = function (modelValue) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('differentValues', modelValue !== scope.otherModelValue);
            };

            scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function () {
                ctrl.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I started to use angular yesterday first time, so sorry if ask some simple things. And as I understood this one it is not the better solutions because from the documentation I can read that $validate() - invoke all validators from the $validators collection. But I need to run just one of them. Can I do that somehow? Or this solution is OK?